# What is the most performant way to submit a POST to an API

Tags: api, curl, sqlcmd

A little background on what I am needing to accomplish. I am a developer of a cloud-based SaaS application. In one instance, my clients use my application to log the receipt of goods as they come across a conveyor line. Directly before the PC where they are logged into my app, there is another Windows PC that is collecting from instruments, the moisture and weight of the item. I (personally not my app) have full access to this pc and its database. I know how I am going to grab the latest record from the db via stored procedure/SQLCMD.

On the receiving end, I have an API endpoint that needs to receive the ID, Weight, Moisture, and ClientID. *This all needs to happen in less than ~2 seconds since they are waiting to add this record to the my software's database.*

What is the most-perfomant way for me to stand up a process that triggers retrieving the record from the db and then calls the API? I also want to update the record flagging success for 200 response. My thoughts were to script all of this in a batch file and use cURL to make the API call. Then call this batch file from a task in windows. But I feel like there may be a better way with less moving parts.

P.S. I am not looking for code solutions per say, just direction or tools that will help, also I am using the AWS stack to host my application.

Answer (score 0):

The most performant way is to use AWS Amplify, its ready aws framework and development environment that can connect your existing DB to a REST API easily

you can check their documentation on how to build it

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js

Comment: Looked at this, and struggling to follow. Are you saying I could install the Amplfy CLI on the local machine with the database and use it to automate a process of sending the data needed to my existing API?